# MySQL INSERT .. UPDATE breaks AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

There are the following two tables:

```
create table lol(id int auto_increment, data int, primary key id(id));
create table lol2(id int auto_increment, data int, primary key id(id));
```

Insert some values:

```
insert into lol2 (data) values (1),(2),(3),(4);
```

Now insert using select:

```
insert into lol (data) select data from lol2;
```

Do it again:

```
insert into lol (data) select data from lol2;
```

Now look at the table:

```
select * from lol;
```

I receive:

```
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |
|  4 |    4 |
|  8 |    1 |
|  9 |    2 |
| 10 |    3 |
| 11 |    4 |
+----+------+
```

I'm puzzled by the gap between 4 and 8... What caused this and how can I do it so that there isn't a gap? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` ?

Comment: Try to drop the tables and run the queries again, it shouldn't do this. When I try it, i have 1 to 8 ids. It's possible that the one query failed once and incremented the ID. Auto increment is not anything like take the maximum number and add 1, it's stored in meta table. So if anything fails, the auto increment will be incremented, but you will not have  the records - you will end up with the gap.

Comment: Given there are 4 lost keys it does seem to be a transaction rollback, and auto numbers are not reused.

Comment: Sorry how do i get the value of innodb_autoinc_lock_mode?

Comment: I tried it again with MyISAM. It does not happen. Perhaps that's why Denis cannot reproduce the issue. Unfortunately my real-world tables have to be InnoDB due to lots of foreign key constraints.

Comment: what transaction rollback could happen for such a simple insert?

Comment: Here's what I further discovered. If the table lol2 had instead had 7 elements to start with, the gap does not appear. But if there were 8 elements, a gap appears between 8 and 16. If there are 16 elements the gap is between 16 and 32. If there were 40 elements the gap is between 40 and 64. As you see, the gap always ends at a power of 2. This seems very puzzling... Anyone has an explanation??

Comment: I got it.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61058

This is a reported bug.

Comment: @javic, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode'` will display the value.

Answer (score 0):

auto_increment does not guarantee to have increments by 1 in the ID column. And it cannot, because as soon as you work with parallel transactions it would break anyways:

```
BEGIN                                  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO lol VALUES(...)            INSERT INTO lol VALUES(..)   
  ...                                    ...
COMMIT                                 ROLLBACK
```

What ids should be assigned by the database? It cannot know in advance which transaction will succeed and which will be rolled back.

If you need a sequential numbering of your records you would use a query which returns that; e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as position, lol.data FROM lol 
INNER JOIN lol2 ON lol.id < lol2.id 
GROUP BY lol.id
```